# Looks like new IMUs doesn't have integrated magnetometers. How to reorient IMU without magnetometer?

Tags: imu, magnetometer

I was searching for some replacement for the old MPU6050, and when I finally thought of ordering ICM-42688-P, I figured out it doesn't have a magnetometer.

Strangely enough, ICM-20948 had a magnetometer, but guess what, its marked as  "NRND: Not recommended for new designs." Which probably means it will also be EOL soon.

Now I really don't care *why* they don't use a magnetometer anymore, because I would only like to have it for one function and one function only: For re-orientation.

So how to re-orient ICM-42688-P, when you don't have a magnetometer? 
What did they figure out that I don't know?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nice to read you Marcus. Look, I can't find the right logic. Maybe I should re-define the question. Let's just say I would like to use a MPU6050, and I would if it wouldn't be EOL. What now?

Comment: @Domenico thanks for making the title refer more closely to the technical question!

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way than using an additional magnetometer. With only 6 axis from gyro and accelerometer there is no way to get information about the initial yaw (assuming you also don't have more sophisticated means of navigation like tracking wireless hotspots or something).

As to why magnetometers are so seldom included in IMUs:
I don't exactly know, but some time ago I simply concluded for myself that the manufacturing processes probably are just to different. I assume low drift, low noise sensors interefere or something...

Comment: You are right, ICM-42688-P IMU is typically going together with the AK8963 magnetometer

Comment: ICM-20948 includes an AKM magnetometer.  TDK has "no plans to EOL" ICM-20948, and not in the next 6 months, but apparently they will stop when they run out of AKM  AK09916C